# Android: Can't access dialog TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-dialog

I am newbie in android development. I am good at Java, but not Android API. This is my testing program for job application, so I need help to solve issue. I made dialog box, which is called by pressing button, but I can't reach dialog's textview (app crashes when i try to reach it - NullPointerException) even Eclipse IDE don't find any problem. I include almost all code, because I don't know what to exclude

custom_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dlgText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

BalticAmadeusActivity.java

```
public class BalticAmadeusActivity extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btnApie;
    Button btnForma;
    Dialog dlgApie;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnApie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnApie);
        btnForma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForma);
        btnApie.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (v.equals(btnForma)) {
                    btnForma();
                } else if (v.equals(btnApie)) {
                    btnApie();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        dlgApie = new Dialog(this.getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dlgApie.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        TextView dlgText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlgText);  
        dlgText.setText("Gera uzduotis"); //at this line, app crashes

        //dlgText.setText("U\u017Eduotis s\u0117kmingai \u012Fgyvendinta");
    }

    private void btnApie() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dlgApie.show();
    }

    private void btnForma() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your main.xml look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the dialog layout(right now you are searching in the activity layout):

```
TextView dlgText = (TextView) dlgApie.findViewById(R.id.dlgText);
```